# Restrict Protege to RDF Schema

Tags: owl, protege, rdfs

Is there any way to restrict a Protege ontology to RDF/RDF Schema, and not use OWL? If yes, how do you do this? If no, are there any other good editors for this purpose?

Comment: 1) There is a Protege Desktop fork for RDF: https://github.com/sszuev/rdf-protege , So, support of any ontologies (not only OWL) is theoretically possible - but right now there is nothing done in this direction. 2) Also, there is Topbraid Composer

Comment: Note that Protégé, since version 4, is an OWL 2 DL editor. RDFS is not a subset of OWL 2 DL, so it's not possible to do everything that is allowed by RDFS in Protégé. However, all OWL 2 DL ontologies can be saved as RDF files, which always be interpreted according to the RDFS regime.